# Using Padrino form helpers and formbuilder - getting started

Tags: ruby, padrino

I've jumped into learning Ruby by going straight to Padrino with Haml.

Most of the Padrino documentation assumes a high-level of knowledge of Ruby/Sinatra etc...

I am looking for samples that I can browse to see how things work.  One specific scenario is doing a simple form.  On my main (index) page I want a "sign up" edit box with button.

```
#app.rb
...
get :index, :map => "/" do
  @user = "test"
  haml: index
end

get :signup, :map => "/signup" do
  render :haml, "%p email:" + params[:email]
end
...
```

In my view:

```
#index.haml
...
#signup
  -form_for @user, '/signup', :id => 'signup' do |f|
    = f.text_field_block :email
    = f.submit_block "Sign up!", :class => 'button'
...
```

This does not work. The `render` in (`/signup`) never does anything.

Note, I know that I need to define my model etc...; but I'm building to to that in my learning.

Instead of just telling me what I'm doing wrong here, what I'd really like is a fairly complete Padrino sample app that uses forms (the blog sample only covers a small part of Padrino's surface area).

Where can I find tons of great Padrino samples? :-)

**EDIT**

The answer below was helpful in pointing me at more samples. But I'm still not finding any joy with what's wrong with my code above.

I've changed this slightly in my hacking and I'm still not getting the `:email` param passed correctly:

```
#index.haml
...
  #signup
     - form_for :User, url(:signup, :create), :method => 'post' do |f|
       = f.text_field_block :email
       = f.submit_block "Sign up!"
...    

#signup.rb
...
post :create do
  @user = User.new(params[:email])
  ...
end
```

**EDIT** Added Model:

```
#user.rb
class User
  include DataMapper::Resource
  property :id, Serial
  property :name, String
  property :email, String
  ...
end
```

When this runs, `params[:email]` is always `nil`.  I've compared this to bunches of other samples and I can't see what the heck I'm doing wrong. Help!

Answer (score 2):

You can browse some example sites here: https://github.com/padrino/padrino-framework/wiki/Projects-using-Padrino

Or you can browse sources of padrinorb.com here: https://github.com/padrino/padrino-web

The best way also is to generate admin: `padrino g admin` where you should see how forms works.

The tag `form` perform by default `post` actions unless you specify `:method => :get|:put|:delete` so in your controller you must change `:get` into `:post`

`post :signup, :map => "/signup" do ...`

Since you are using `form_for :user` params are in `params[:user]` so to get email you need to puts `params[:user][:email]`

Comment: Link to `Projects-using-Padrino` was super helpful. I searched and searched and never saw that. Note `admin` uses partials and I am not (yet) so it was not helpful. I'm still not out of the woods, but your answer helped. Thanks.

Comment: Also, the `render` I was asking about is in the `:signup` handler. The problem I have is `params[:email]` is always `nil`...

Comment: try with a simple `text_field :email`

Comment: also remember that by default `form`(s) perform `post` action, so your controller must be: `post :signup, :map => "/signup"`

Comment: I tried `text_field :email` and same prob. Also, I am using `post`.  See the 2nd example in my question above.  Appreciate you trying to help!!!!

Comment: try to do `params.to_yaml` at the end of your action removing `render`

Comment: FOUND! Since you are using `form_for :user` params are in `params[:user]` so to get email you need to puts `params[:user][:email]`

Comment: You rock. That raises 2 questions for me.  1) How would I do my view if I wanted just `params[:email]` to work?  2) Now why does `@user = User.new(params[:user][:email])` err with `undefined method 'each' for "test@test.com":String`?

Comment: Note I added my User model above to further clarify.

Comment: 1) to use params[:email] you should use `=text_field_tag :email`

Comment: 2) to use User.new you should pass an hash not a string so `User.new(params[:user])`